# What is the best practice to write the debugging and production code at the same time?

Tags: android, swift, debugging

I develop iOS apps and use swift and Xcode now. I often write like this when I use a test code for debug.

```
//test
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
//set bicolor
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

If it's test mode (before release app), I want to set backgroundColor in red. When I submit the app to store, the test code that set backgroundColor to red will be comment out and The backgroundColor will be set clear.

What is the best practice to write the debugging  and production code at the same time?. Is the abouve is good practice or not?.

Comment: Do you mean like you have 1 type of color when in develop mode but production should be different?

Comment: be more descriptive in your question. besides, what is that code example trying to say? All I get from it is that you have put some, imho bad and non-descriptive, comments and you're changing the same object's background color twice.

Comment: When you say test do you mean to say that you would be commenting out the actual code and test ? If so then you would have lots of unwanted pieces of code in your app.

Comment: @Vollan, staticVoidMan and GoodSp33d I'm sorry I didn't subscribe enough. I mean if it's test mode (before release app), I want to set backgroundColor in red. When I submit the app to store, the test code that set backgroundColor to red will be comment out and The backgroundColor will be set clear.

Comment: @bao Then the correct solution is using `#if DEVELOPMENT` or `#if RELEASE` with `#endif` as mentioned in answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is use if development

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
#if DEVELOPMENT
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
#endif
```

or

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
#if RELEASE
label.background = UIColor.clear
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 **#pragma_mark** available in swift same as Objective-C:

1. // MARK: - `write your text here`
2. // TODO: - `write your text here`
3. // FIXME: - `write your text here`

You can use `-` to add separator line.

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift flags DEBUG and RELEASE, you can separate the code for DEBUG and RELEASE

https://kitefaster.com/2016/01/23/how-to-specify-debug-and-release-flags-in-xcode-with-swift/

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use the following code:

```
#if RELEASE
    // release only code
#else
    // debug only code
#endif
```

I normally write following method in Android

If you want some line of code for debugging and production,  you can do the following,

Create a global boolean value like below in GlobalVariableClass,

`public boolean debug=true`

Then you can write code like,

```
if(GlobalVariableClass.debug){
    //debug code
}else{
   //Production code
}
```

It also helpfull for log data as ,

```
If(GlobalVariableClass.debug){
   Log.e("TAG","log message");
}
```

So for the production time, you need to change the `debug` in `GlobalVariableClass` to `false`